# de-activating Wordpress plugin "Jetpack", all oPinterest embeds become broken

Tags: wordpress, plugins

When I de-activate the Wordpress plugin called "Jetpack", ALL of my thousands of Pinterest embeds become broken.

The thing is, Wordress Gutenberg blocks have a Standard Pinterest block, but since I had Jetpack installed for so long, all of my Pinterest embeds are handled by the Jetpack plugin.

But I want to delete this plugin for pagespeed reasons.

But when I de-activate the plugin, all my Pinterest embeds simply become PLAIN URL's on my site, which is obviously a big problem for the visitors.

Now, is there a way to MASS-edit all of these Pinterest embeds to use the Gutenberg Pinterest block instead?

I hope there's a way to do this. I'd be willing to pay for a solution even.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a simple way to mass-edit all of your Pinterest embeds to use the Gutenberg Pinterest block. You would need to manually go through each post or page that contains a Pinterest embed and replace it with the Gutenberg Pinterest block.

One option could be to use a plugin that allows you to search and replace text in your WordPress posts and pages. You can use this plugin to search for the Jetpack Pinterest embed code and replace it with the Gutenberg Pinterest block code. However, be cautious when using a plugin for this as it could potentially break your website if not used correctly.

OR

Another option would be to write a custom script to perform this task. You can try the following code and see if it works:

```
<?php

// Get all posts and pages
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => array('post', 'page'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));

// Loop through all posts and pages
foreach($posts as $post) {
    // Get the content of the post or page
    $content = $post->post_content;
    
    // Check if the Jetpack Pinterest embed code is present in the content
    if(strpos($content, 'data-pin-do="embedPin"') !== false) {
        // Replace the Jetpack Pinterest embed code with the Gutenberg Pinterest block code
        $content = str_replace('data-pin-do="embedPin"', '', $content);
        $content = str_replace('<a data-pin-do="embedPin"', '<!-- wp:pinterest/embed-pin -->', $content);
        $content = str_replace('></a>', '<!-- /wp:pinterest/embed-pin -->', $content);
        
        // Update the post or page with the new content
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID' => $post->ID,
            'post_content' => $content
        ));
    }
}

?>
```

Please note that this is just a basic example, and there may be some variations in the Jetpack Pinterest embed code that would need to be accounted for in the script. It's also important to thoroughly test this script on a staging environment before running it on a live site.

As a general rule, it's always a good idea to make a backup of your website before making any changes, especially ones involving code.